# Collections.shuffle(a) magic?

Tags: java, java-8

Magic after
System.out.println("*****");
Collections.shuffle(a);

~$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Integer> a = Arrays.asList(1,  3,  5, 9, 14);
        Collections.shuffle(a);

        System.out.println(a);

        List<Integer> b = a.subList(0, a.size() - 1);
        List<Integer> b1 = new ArrayList<>(a.subList(0, a.size() - 1));
        System.out.println(b);
        System.out.println(b1);

        System.out.println("*****");
        Collections.shuffle(a);
        System.out.println(a);

        Collections.shuffle(b);
        System.out.println(b);

        Collections.shuffle(b1);
        System.out.println(b1);
}

[14, 1, 9, 3, 5]
[14, 1, 9, 3]
[14, 1, 9, 3]
*****
[14, 9, 3, 5, 1]
[3, 14, 9, 5]
[1, 14, 9, 3]
```

b after shuffle(a) not eq b after a.subList(0, a.size() - 1); 
\

UPD

**Yep! step by step! 1) create a 2) create b sublist a 3) shuffle(a) Why shuffle(a) modify b ?**

UPD 2

**Why is correct ?  Why this is true when I shuffle b I change the order in a ?**

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> a = Arrays.asList(1,  3,  5, 9, 14);
        Collections.shuffle(a);
        System.out.println(a);
        List<Integer> b = a.subList(0, a.size() - 1);
        System.out.println(b);
        System.out.println("*****");
        Collections.shuffle(b);
        System.out.println(a);



        System.exit(0);
}

[1, 9, 3, 5, 14]
[1, 9, 3, 5]
*****
[3, 9, 5, 1, 14]
```

Comment: It's really not clear to me what you mean - your final sentence doesn't explain exactly what you expected or more importantly *why* you expected it.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Are you wondering why shuffeling actually shuffels the Collection? I mean... it's what it's supposed to do...

Comment: It seems like you have three independent lists and you shuffled each of them separately.

Comment: Actually they are not independent. `b` is a sub-list of `a`, so it is backed by the same ArrayList instance.

Comment: Note that you are shuffling `b` and `b1` before printing, so even _if_ those would retain the same order of `a` then they would print in different order after shufling.

Answer (score 8):

`b` is [a **view** on the first 4 elements of `a`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-). If those elements change in `a`, they also change in `b`.

So you have, initally:

- `a = {14, 1, 9, 3, 5}`
- `b = {14, 1, 9, 3};`

After shuffling `a`, you have:

- `a = {14, 9, 3, 5, 1}`
- `b = {14, 9, 3, 5}`

`b1` on the other is an independent list and changes made to `a` after the creation of `b1` have no impact on `b1`.

Comment: As declared here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-

Answer (score 1):

> b after shuffle(a) not eq b after a.subList(0, a.size() - 1);

That's because you also shuffle both `b1` and `b` after you shuffled `a`, thus neither `b` nor `b1` will show what you expected. Instead, you should shuffle *only* `a` to see that `b`, being a view on a sublist of `a`, assumes the same order while `b1`, being a new list, stays independent of the re-ordering of `a`.

```
List<Integer> a = Arrays.asList(1,  3,  5, 9, 14);
List<Integer> b = a.subList(0, a.size() - 1);
List<Integer> b1 = new ArrayList<>(a.subList(0, a.size() - 1));
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(b);
System.out.println(b1);

System.out.println("*****");
Collections.shuffle(a); // shuffle a, but do not shuffle b and b1!
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(b);
System.out.println(b1);
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 5, 9, 14]
[1, 3, 5, 9]
[1, 3, 5, 9]
*****
[5, 14, 1, 9, 3]
[5, 14, 1, 9]
[1, 3, 5, 9]
```

Comment: Yep!  step by step!

1) create a
2) create b sublist a

3)

shuffle(a)

Why

shuffle(a)

modify b ?

Comment: thx List<E> subList(int fromIndex,
                int toIndex)
Returns a view of the portion of this list between the specified fromIndex, inclusive, and toIndex, exclusive. (If fromIndex and toIndex are equal, the returned list is empty.) The returned list is backed by this list, so non-structural changes in the returned list are reflected in this list, and vice-versa. The returned list supports all of the optional list operations supported by this list.